# How to insert a record and return new id as an output parameter in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to insert a new record while returning the new id as a out-parameter value using the following sql:

```
Insert into ERRORS  ( ErrorId, Date, ErrorInfo )  values  ( :ItemDate, :Text )  returning ErrorId into :ID
```

I get the following error:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException occurred
  BaseMessage=syntax error at or near "into"
  Code=42601
  ColumnName=""
  ConstraintName=""
  DataTypeName=""
  Detail=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  ErrorSql=Insert into ERRORS  ( ErrorId, Date, ErrorInfo )  values  ( (('2014-04-02 08:16:36.045969')::timestamp), (('Test 333 4/2/2014 8:16:36 AM')::text) )  returning ErrorId into 
  File=src\backend\parser\scan.l
  Hint=""
  HResult=-2147467259
  Line=1053
  Message=ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "into"
  Position=168
  Routine=scanner_yyerror
  SchemaName=""
  Severity=ERROR
  Source=Npgsql
  TableName=""
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__9.MoveNext()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject(Boolean cleanup)
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResultInternal()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean preparedStatement, NpgsqlRowDescription rowDescription)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at FrozenElephant.Symbiotic.ObjectWriter.Create(IDatabaseTypesFactory factory, Object value, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean performCommitClose) in E:\Dev\FrozenElephant\SymbioticORM\Symbiotic\Symbiotic\ObjectWriter.vb:line 423
  InnerException:
```

I also tried removing the last "into" but does not work either.

Comment: What was the error message when you removed the last into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an out parameter, you have to use ExecuteReader with npgsql:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"Insert into ERRORS(Date, ErrorInfo) values(:ItemDate, :Text) returning ErrorId", conn);

...Add your inpout parameters...

NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int errorId;

while (reader.Read())
{
    errorId = reader.GetInt32(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example SQL will yield a result set with a single row containing the new ErrorId:

```sql
CREATE TABLE errors(ErrorId SERIAL, date TIMESTAMP, ErrorInfo VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO errors(Date, ErrorInfo)
VALUES (now(), 'abc') 
RETURNING ErrorId
```

One problem with your expression is that you have ErrorId in the insert into list, but not a value for it.

Comment: Yes, typically you exclude the auto increment value or "Serial" in this case. But I need a return parameter.

Comment: The ErrorId would be returned in my example, but it would become a normal result set. In Java I would do executeQuery() instead of executeUpdate().

Comment: The `RETURNING` part determines the columns in the returned result set.

Comment: yes I understand all that, I want a parameter, this works in oracle. Sql server it's your next result.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't do out parameters from queries (which is what this ends up as from the server side), but perhaps your .NET driver has some magic that can do that for you.

Comment: do you have any documentation on that claim?

Comment: Not really, it's just not a concept that exist in PostgreSQL so it is not something that they explicitly document. PL/pgSQL procedures can have out parameters (Oracle style), but that's not the same thing.